# Why does one Vue instance update with the data while another view instance doesn't?

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue for the first time, and am confused about why one of my Vue objects keeps updating when the data changes, and the other Vue object won't.

I have a JavaScript module like this to basically just hold data:

```
var MyModule = (function(){

    const info = {
        requestCount: 20,
        arrayOfItems: []
    }

    return info;
})();
```

I have this html:

```
<span id='requestCounter' class='badge'>{{count}}</span>

<table id='vueTable'><tr v-for="item in items"><td>{{item.description}}</td></tr></table>
```

And lastly, I have this JavaScript file to do everything:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var mainTable = new Vue({
        el: '#vueTable',
        data: {
            items: MyModule.arrayOfItems
        }
    });

    var requestCounterVue = new Vue({
        el: '#requestCounter',
        data: {
            count: MyModule.requestCount
        }
    });
}
```

On the first runthrough, everything works as intended. Changing the `MyModule.arrayOfItems` works correctly, the table updates depending on what is in the array. However, changing `MyModule.requestCount` doesn't do anything. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

(Note, my example is simplified to make my question easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the data in your Vue objects from MyModule. This does not make MyModule a proper store or controller. The weird behavior is not that `requestCount` doesn't react, but that `arrayOfItems` does.

The reason the array behaves as it does is that objects are passed by reference, so when you initialize `items`, Vue gets hold of the actual array object and does its magic on it. Effectively, MyModule provides an external handle to your Vue data.

`requestCount`, on the other hand, is a simple value, not an object, so it is passed by value, and there is absolutely no relationship between the member in MyModule and the data item in `requestCounterVue`.

Answer (score 2):

*Roy is exactly right. I'm just leaving this here because I was typing while he answered, and possibly more explanation couldn't hurt*.

`MyModule` doesn't become reactive just because you use it to initialize values in your Vues. I expect the reason `arrayOfItems` is working the way you expect is because you are not actually setting it to a new array, you are mutating the existing array.

For example, your Vue using the array is defined here.

```
var mainTable = new Vue({
    el: '#vueTable',
    data: {
        items: MyModule.arrayOfItems
    }
});
```

If you add a value to `MyModule.arrayOfItems` like this

```
MyModule.arrayOfItems.push('my new value')
```

then your Vue will show the new value. This is because `mainTable.items` and `MyModule.arrayOfItems` are pointers to the *same* array.

If instead, however, you modified `MyModule.arrayOfItems` like this

```
MyModule.arrayOfItems = ['my','new','array']
```

Then `mainTable` will **not** show the updated array. This is because you've changed it to a **completely different** array. In other words, `MyModule.arrayOfItems !== mainTable.items`.

This is also the reason changing `MyModule.count` to a new value is not reflected in `requestCounterVue`. `MyModule.count` is a primitive value  and when you initialized `requestCounterVue` with `count`, it used a copy of the value and made the copy reactive. Changing `MyModule.count` will have no effect.

If you wanted to see the changes reflected, what you might do is initialize your Vues this way

```
var mainTable = new Vue({
    el: '#vueTable',
    data: MyModule
});
```

When the Vue is instantiated, `MyModule` will be turned into a reactive object and changes will be reflected for both `count` and `arrayOfItems`.